# Solve or get rid of pattern matching error in tsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I solve / get rid of a pattern matching error shown in Visual Studio Code?

In my TypeScript application I get an error in the `tsconfig.json` file, mentioning to not find an index.ts due to the matching of a certain pattern `**/*`. The application still compiles and runs without any issues. The error only shows in Visual Studio Code. To compile the application I use Webpack, where I have defined and `index.tsx` file as the entry point, and not an `index.ts` file.

[image]

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main/ts/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
  },
};
```

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rest": "^1.3.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.0.3",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
"include": ["src/**/*"],
```

To your `tsconfig.json`

It may help .  If not you have to   reopen vscode it  will fix this, but it's a little bit annoying

Comment: Ok, it seems that reopening vscode did the trick. Is this a known bug in vscode? Or is there a kind of reload that needs to be done after adding i.e. TypeScript to the project?

Comment: No this is a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43838)  in  TypeScript

Comment: Still a bug (as of November 1, 2023)...

Answer (score 1):

### Reopen your VS code or Restart the TS Server!

You can **restart the VsCode** or **restart the TS Server**.

To restart VS code `Ctrl + Shift + P` and then search and execute `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`

This happens because of a typescript problem, to know more check the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43838).

Credits to @Socrates for the answer improvement.

Comment: In other words, this issue is still the same (as of October 26, 2023) and currently needs to be solved by restarting the TS Server within VS Code. Ctrl + Shift + P and then search and execute `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`. That solves this issue until there is a better and more automatic solution.

Comment: I added this to the answer.